# How to solve error: "Flash plugin is not installed." in Kofax Kapow RPA 10.4.0.1?

Tags: rpa, kofax, kapow

After loaded a web URL in **Kofax Kapow RPA 10.4.0.1**, I am getting this error("**Flash plugin is not installed**.")

How to solve this error please help me.

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Already follow the steps from Kofax ofical site : https://knowledge.kofax.com/Robotic_Process_Automation/Configuration/How_to_enable_support_for_Flash_in_Chromium_Embedded_Framework_(CEF)

but its not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want to interact with the Flash content present on the page:

- Disable JavaScript, either at the Load Page action or globally for the robot. This will allow the for much faster processing, but JavaScript could be needed for other parts of the page: [image: disable JavaScript]
- Tell the Error handling on the Load Page action to ignore errors: [image: ignore errors]

If you need to interact with Flash, follow the guide you linked (which you already did) and then make sure that you use the CEF. This isn't done with a simple Page Load action, but with Desktop Automation (using a local device):
[image: Flash loaded in CEF]